# Extending $resource of angularjs using IResourceClass of typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am developing SPA using Asp.Net Web API and AngularJS. I also use TypeScript to get static typing. So, I added DefinitelyTyped angularjs.

As I am using RESTfull services. I thought of using $resource of angularjs. now I $resource doesn't have any inbuilt method for PUT http method. So i decided to add my own as follows.

```
var employees = $resource('/api/employee/:id',{id:'@id'},{"update":{ method: "PUT", isArray:false }};
```

Now, as you can see, Its easy to do in normal AngularJS. I wanted to go through TypeScript route and define custom interface which extends [IResourceClass](https://github.com/daptiv/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular-resource.d.ts) . documentation of this interface explains like this.

> // Baseclass for everyresource with default actions. 
>   // If you define your new actions for the resource, you will need 
>   // to extend this interface and typecast the ResourceClass to it.

I am really not able to make out how to extend this interface. It keeps coming up with some errors about syntax. Can some one explain how to extend this interface and add Update method which in turn calls PUT method on my controllers.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped, or if you are still stuck in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: There's some very useful documentation about $resource usage with TypeScript on the AngularJS DefinitelyTyped page - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angularjs

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First define your model, the interface that will describes your employee.

```
// Define an interface of the object you want to use, providing it's properties
interface IEmployee extends ng.resource.IResource<IEmployee>
{
    id: number;
    firstName : string;
    lastName : string;
}
```

Then create an interface that describes the resource you will create.

```
// Define your resource, adding the signature of the custom actions
interface IEmployeeResource extends ng.resource.IResourceClass<IEmployee>
{
    update(IEmployee) : IEmployee;
}
```

Create the `EmployeeResource` factory:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']).factory('EmployeeResource', 
    ['$resource', ($resource : ng.resource.IResourceService) : IEmployeeResource => {

        // Define your custom actions here as IActionDescriptor
        var updateAction : ng.resource.IActionDescriptor = {
            method: 'PUT',
            isArray: false
        };

        // Return the resource, include your custom actions
        return <IEmployeeResource> $resource('/api/employee/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            update: updateAction
        });

    }]);
```

Inject your `EmployeeResource` into a controller:

```
myApp.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 'EmployeeResource', ($scope, Employee : IEmployeeResource) => 
{
    // Get all employees
    var employees : Array<IEmployee> = Employee.query();

    // Get specific employee, and change their last name
    var employee : IEmployee = Employee.get({ id: 123 });
    employee.lastName = 'Smith';
    employee.$save();

    // Custom action
    var updatedEmployee : IEmployee = Employee.update({ id: 100, firstName: "John" });
}]);
```

---

Creating a new employee instance:

You can create an instance of type `IEmployee` by `new`ing the `EmployeeResource` factory.

```
myApp.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 'EmployeeResource', ($scope, Employee : IEmployeeResource) => 
{
    var myEmployee : IEmployee = new Employee({ firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith"});
    myEmployee.$save();
}
```

So in the case above we inject our `IEmployeeResource` as `Employee`. We can then `new` this object to create an `IEmployee`.

Comment: This does answer my question but doesn't provide exact solution I was looking for. I wanted to have a generic way to define update on $resource. So, i don't have to declare it in every controller. But thanks for the solution.

Comment: If you post answers, make sure they at least COMPILE. I think
 
[$resource, ($resource : ng.resource.IResourceService) : IEmployeeResource =>

must be

['$resource', ($resource : ng.resource.IResourceService) : IEmployeeResource => 

mind the quotes.

Comment: @LocalJoost I have fixed the small typo. If you find typos feel free to edit them yourself, that's the SO way. *Respectively please don't tell me how to answer questions in a community to which you are relatively new, it's rude.*

Comment: I was not aware I could do that. I don't write on SO that often

Comment: @LocalJoost It works for me. It's likely it appears empty while the promise is resolved, after which it is populated. That's just how AngularJS works. Your `Employee.query({}, (d) => { var a = d; })` works because it is calling your resolved function with the result. This is by design.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but your code suggests that is works synchronously ;) Now I see what is happening.

Comment: Good answer. One thing that strikes me as odd (although it compiles fine in playground and on the github compiler) is

    interface IEmployee extends ng.resource.IResource<IEmployee>

Seems strange that a type can be defined using itself.

Comment: @KnarfaLingus I entirely agree with you there. That made me take a step back too. I guess it's just one of the those quirks about TypeScript that it bends to fit JavaScript so in this case doesn't fit the convention.

Comment: I had a hard time getting this to work, and in the end decided to make a full writeup of how my feeble brain finally seems to grasp it. You can find it here, including a compiling - and running - demo solution. http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.nl/2014/07/angularjs-typescript-using-resource-to.html

Comment: Awesome answer!  Very detailed.  I was struggling over this issue; this answer showed some underlying flaws in my TS architecture I needed to fix.  Thanks for the thorough answer and the time you put in.

Comment: @Gustyn Thanks. I am glad it helped. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: @Scott, any chance you could extend this answer to include saving a completely new `IEmployee`?  I can't figure out a way to instantiate an `IEmployee` without implementing everything from `ng.resource.IResource<>`.

Comment: @MushinNoShin I have added the example of creating a new `IEmployee`. This is done by `new`ing on the injected factory instance.

Comment: @Scott, Thanks for doing this so soon!

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with Scott's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786326/2677975

I do have one addition:
In my project, I've create the class `ServiceModel<T>`, which implements the interface `IActionDescriptor`.

```
module Common.ApiService {
    export class HttpHeaders {
        'Content-Type': string;
        Accept: string;
    }

    export class ServiceModel<T> implements ng.resource.IActionDescriptor {
        public method: string = 'GET';
        public params: T;
        public isArray: boolean = false;
        public url: string;
        public headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
    } 
}
```

Then, I can setup the method in my controller, just as Scott did, but now, the IDE will have type completion on the headers (and the params later on)

```
export interface IProfileServiceResource extends ng.resource.IResourceClass<IProfileDataModelDef> {
    SaveProfileImage(profileImageUri: Profile.Model.UserProfileModel): ng.resource.IResource<Array<any>>;
}

export class ProfileApiService 
    implements Common.ApiService.IApiServiceBase<IProfileServiceResource> {

    public SaveProfileImage: Common.ApiService.ServiceModel<Profile.Model.UserProfileModel>;

    constructor() {    
        this.SaveProfileImage = new Common.ApiService.ServiceModel<Profile.Model.UserProfileModel>();
        this.SaveProfileImage.method = "POST";
        this.SaveProfileImage.url = "/api/Profile/SaveProfileImage";
        this.SaveProfileImage.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/json';
}
```

I made this as an additional answer, since it only serves to provide types for the `headers` and the `params`.