# Typescript, $resource and custom descriptor

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a dataAccessService class that I want to add a custom action(copy) to my class. How can I add that so typescript can call dataAccessService.copy()? I looked at [Extending $resource of angularjs using IResourceClass of typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685104/extending-resource-of-angularjs-using-iresourceclass-of-typescript/21786326#21786326) but its using a factory and I would like to use a service

```
module rebateMaintenance.common {

interface IDataAccessService {
    getRebateResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IRebateResource> ;
}

interface IRebateResource
    extends ng.resource.IResource<rebateMaintenance.domain.IRebate>{
}

export class DataAcessService
    implements IDataAccessService {

    static $inject = ["$resource"];
    constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {

    }

    getRebateResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IRebateResource> {
        return this.$resource("http://localhost:48679/api/rebate/:id", null,
            {
                copy: { method: 'POST', url: "http://localhost:48679/copyrebate/:id"}
            }
        );
    }

}
angular.module("common.services")
    .service("dataAccessService",
    DataAcessService);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I got it. The key is to cast to the interface type when returning from getCopyRebateResource method

```
module rebateMaintenance.common {

interface IDataAccessService {
    getRebateResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IRebateResource>;
    getCopyRebateResource(): ICopyRebateResourceClass;
}

interface IRebateResource
    extends ng.resource.IResource<rebateMaintenance.domain.IRebate> {
}

interface ICopyRebateResource
    extends ng.resource.IResource<domain.ICopyRebate> {
}

interface ICopyRebateResourceClass
    extends ng.resource.IResourceClass<any> {
    copy(params: Object, success?: Function, error?: Function): domain.ICopyRebate;
}

export class DataAcessService
    implements IDataAccessService {

    static $inject = ["$resource"];
    constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService ) {

    }

    getRebateResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IRebateResource> {
        return this.$resource("http://localhost:48679/api/rebate/:id", null,
            {
                'update': { method: 'PUT' }
            }
        );
    }

    getCopyRebateResource() {
        return     <ICopyRebateResourceClass>this.$resource("http://localhost:48679/copyrebate/:id", null,
            {
                copy: { method: 'POST' }
            }
        )
    }
}
angular.module("common.services")
    .service("dataAccessService",
    DataAcessService);
}
```